# 1.wrong credentials is running pass in data driven-Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, data-driven-tests

1. jmeter reads credentials from CSV. even if I have wrong credentials in the csv file (1/5login credentials) script shows successful.Does it check database while running? Which means 2 credentials is wrong, it supposed to shows fail, but it shows pass result(app angular JS type)
2. In the CSV file, I have 5 credentials and threads also 5...but in the output I got only 4 results

Answer (score 0):

JMeter neither checks response nor database. In case of web applications JMeter automatically treads [HTTP response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) < 400 as successful so if your web server responded with HTTP Status Code 200 (OK) - you will have "green" result even if your login wasn't successful.

You might wish to add i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to your request to ensure that response doesn't contain error messages or contain something, which indicates a logged in user, i.e. "Welcome" text or whatever.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally failing JMeter samplers.